# Filling in capped off torus in tikz 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

I am trying to draw a capped off torus in tikz 3d, see MWE below. I'd like the surface to be colored in gray for the first picture, and everything below the blue line to be colored in gray for the second one. Is it possible to do this and changing as little as possible about the picture (so it will still be in the same style with some other pictures I made)?

Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[]{calc}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{0}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
        \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{0}
        \tdplotdrawarc[bottom color= gray, top color= gray!40, tdplot_main_coords]{(0,-0.08,0.76604444311)}{0.64278760968}{0}{360}{}{} 
        \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{1}{-140.5}{140.5}{}{}   
        \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{.25}{0}{360}{}{}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{0}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_main_coords,color=blue, dashed]{(0,-0.08,0.76604444311)}{0.64278760968}{0}{180}{}{} 
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_main_coords,color=blue]{(0,-0.08,0.76604444311)}{0.64278760968}{180}{360}{}{}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{1}{-140.5}{140.5}{}{}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{.25}{0}{360}{}{} 
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{-90}{0}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords, color=blue]{(O)}{1}{-39.5}{39.5}{}{}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It will be difficult to apply a shading (i.e. a gradient to simulate 3D) that suits a torus ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that I am not able (or willing) to base the answer on the precise code you provide because I do not understand where all the magical numbers come from. However, it is easy to compute the critical angles, and with this information shading is straightforward.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords,
    declare function={h=0.75;
    tcrit(\x)=atan2(sin(\x),cos(\x)*sin(\tdplotmaintheta));},
    radius=1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myalpha}{tcrit(asin(h))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myr}{sqrt(1-h*h)}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \draw[bottom color= gray, top color= gray!40, tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,h) circle[radius=\myr];
    \draw[fill=gray,even odd rule]
    [tdplot_main_coords]
    (0,0,h)+(90+\tdplotmaintheta:\myr) arc[start angle=90+\tdplotmaintheta,end angle=450-\tdplotmaintheta,radius=\myr]
    [tdplot_screen_coords] -- (\myalpha:1) arc[start angle=\myalpha,end angle=-180-\myalpha] (O) circle[radius=0.25];
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords,
    declare function={h=0.75;
    tcrit(\x)=atan2(sin(\x),cos(\x)*sin(\tdplotmaintheta));},
    radius=1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myalpha}{tcrit(asin(h))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myr}{sqrt(1-h*h)}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \draw[fill=gray,even odd rule]
    [tdplot_main_coords]
    (0,0,h)+(90+\tdplotmaintheta:\myr) arc[start angle=90+\tdplotmaintheta,end angle=450-\tdplotmaintheta,radius=\myr]
    [tdplot_screen_coords] -- (\myalpha:1) arc[start angle=\myalpha,end angle=-180-\myalpha] (O) circle[radius=0.25];
    \draw[dashed,blue]  [tdplot_main_coords]
    (0,0,h)+(90+\tdplotmaintheta:\myr) arc[start angle=90+\tdplotmaintheta,end angle=90-\tdplotmaintheta,radius=\myr];
    \draw[blue,tdplot_screen_coords] (\myalpha:1) arc[start angle=\myalpha,end angle=180-\myalpha];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, thank you! Could you explain what critical angles are/ give a reference where I can find information about using them? My 'magic' numbers came from calculating by hand which height the arc reaches.

Comment: @vheerde It is implicit in the tikz-3dplot manual, which explains what which vectors correspond to the horizontal or vertical directions on the screen, and which one is perpendicular. This allows you to compute the angles at which arcs turn (in)visible.